# WooCommerce output product tax rate (WC 3.0+)

Tags: woocommerce

I need to output the product tax rate (in % value) from a product on the single product page. 
I have tried several code snippets but so far I only get either the tax class name or the text value "Array" back.

Does anybody know how to get this value? 
My shop sells food (6% TAX VAT) and non-food (21% TAX VAT) products.
All prices are shown excl. VAT but the tax class and rates have been set correctly and applied to all products.

When a customer check the product page, I have to show them (by law) which TAX VAT applies to the product.

I have the below snippet so far. 
This is showing "Array" as output.

```
// For WooCommerce Version 3.0+ (only)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'exbtw_melding', 20 );

function exbtw_melding(){
    global $product;
    $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates( $product->get_tax_class() );
    echo 'Alle vermelde prijzen zijn excl. <b>'. $tax_rates . ' BTW</b> / 
    Tous les prix indiqués sont hors <b> '. $tax_rates . ' TVA</b>';
}
```

Any help please?

Thanks!

Fabio

Answer (score 5):

This is what I have used:

```
function woocommerce_template_display_tax() {
    global $product;
    $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates( $product->get_tax_class() );
    if (!empty($tax_rates)) {
        $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates);
        echo sprintf(_x('Inclusive %.2f %% tax', 'Text for tax rate. %.2f = tax rate', 'wptheme.foundation'), $tax_rate['rate']);
    }
}
```